# Org-table color entries that match a predicate

Tags: org-mode, faces, org-table, colors

Say we have the following table:

```
| Student | Grade |
|---------+-------|
| Foo     |     7 |
| Bar     |   5.5 |
| Baz     |     9 |
```

Is there a way to change the face color of an entry when a condition is matched, e.g., change the color of Grade < 6, or change the color of names starting with B?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, [this may be what you're looking for. ](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/can-i-format-cells-in-an-org-mode-table-differently-depending-on-a-formula)